# Unable to revoke privileges in Postgres even though revoke statements succeed

Tags: postgresql, psql

How do you revoke all privileges for a user in Postgres and then drop the user?

The docs say it should be as simple as:

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE database FROM user;
DROP USER user;
```

However, if I open my psql prompt, I get the bizarre output:

```
mydb=> REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE mydb FROM myuser;
REVOKE
mydb=> DROP USER myuser;
ERROR:  role "myuser" cannot be dropped because some objects depend on it
DETAIL:  privileges for schema myschema
```

Uh, what? Ok, so I just need to explicitly revoke permissions on "myschema"? But then I get:

```
mydb=> REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA myschema FROM myuser;
REVOKE
mydb=> DROP USER myuser;
ERROR:  role "myuser" cannot be dropped because some objects depend on it
DETAIL:  privileges for schema myschema
```

It's saying it's successfully revoking all database and schema access, but yet schema access remains, preventing me from dropping the user.

Even more bizarrely, if I try to confirm the user has that schema access with:

```
SELECT *
FROM pg_namespace
WHERE has_schema_privilege('myuser', 'myschema', 'USAGE');
```

it returns nothing except "pg_catalog", "information_schema", and "public".

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Your query against `pg_namespace` doesn't do what you think it does. Perhaps you should simply try revoking the schema privilege, which is what the error message suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is not talking about privileges on tables in the schema, but about privileges on the schema itself.

```
REVOKE ALL ON SCHEMA myschema FROM myuser;
```